# Most efficient way to check if a number is within a large amount of ranges in vba

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I am attempting to code what sounds like either a segment or interval tree, but I'm not sure how to do it in VBA. Basically, what I am trying to do is take a list of numbers and seeing if they fall under a list of ranges. In the real world, the numbers refer to customers, and these ranges are assigned to different company sites. So for example, let's say we had 3 numbers (aka customers) to input: 156000 166000 and 256000. Site 1 gets any customers between 145000 and 149000, 152300 to 155000, and 165000 to 165999. Site 2 gets any customers between 156000 and 159000, 162000 and 165000, and 255000 to 275000. Site 3 get any customers between 166000 to 180000. So I would want the function to be able to tell that customer one and three would go to site 2, and customer two would go to site three. So each site has about one to eight nonconsecutive ranges associated with it.

The amount of numbers(customers) being checked against ranges can vary from 1 to 5000, but the amount of ranges is about 3000 spread across 497 different sites, which will slowly increase over time but will be statically updated. Customer numbers will be copy/pasted to column K in my Excel worksheet. The site ranges I will have in another sheet in the same workbook. Initially I tried to just do tons of if/then statements, but it seems like doing a list of 3000 if/then statements cant be the best way. Then I thought about doing a tiered list of if/then statements, by initially just looking at the first two numbers of the customer number stored in column L, like:

```
If Worksheets("Input").Range("L" & x) >= 14 and _
If Worksheets("Input").Range("L" & x) =< 19 then

    If Worksheets("Input").Range("K" & x) >= 145000 and _
    If Worksheets("Input").Range("K" & x) >= 146000 then

      [code to assign customer to specific site]
    End If

    If Worksheets("Input").Range("K" & x) >= 245000 and _
    If Worksheets("Input").Range("K" & x) >= 246000 then

      [code to assign customer to specific site]
    End If
End If
```

The problem with doing it this way is that each site has non consecutive ranges, so I'm not sure if making multi tiered if/then statements would even be able to work.

Anyone have any ideas as to how this could efficiently be done with such a large amount of ranges?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using VLookup? What you describe would be a nightmare to maintain in code format

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to do using VLookup (Range) combined with a smaller conditional test to ensure the empty spaces between ranges don't pass. No VBA needed:

[image: Excel view]